# Alexa in Custom web application

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Can we use Alexa SDK use AVS API services in let's say search bar of some web application, Have any one tried creating such web application? or came across such web application.
This can be considered as creating custom echosim application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Amazon [LEX](https://aws.amazon.com/lex/) is better option for your scenario. You have to manage client side operations like capturing user voice, making a API call to LEX backend though.

Comment: Yes Lex is good choice, but There is a price tag along with it.